# ASP.NET MVC ModelMetadata

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть такой вот метод действия

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.M = ViewData.ModelMetadata == null;
            return View();
        }
```

И есть к нему представление с именем Index

```
    @if (ViewData.ModelMetadata == null)
    {
        @:null
    }
    @if (ViewData.ModelMetadata != null)
    {
        @:not a null
    }
    @ViewBag.M
```

Представлению не передается никакой модели и само представление НЕстроготипизированное. Однако возникает вопрос почему в методе действия `Index` `ViewData.ModelMetadata` выходит `true` - то есть = `null` , но при этом в представлении `ViewData.ModelMetadata` уже не равняется `null` ?? Почему так ?? Всем заранее спасибо

Comment: Вы устанавливаете ViewData.ModelMetadata=null и удивляетесь почему в представлении срабатывает условие выводящее null?или я чего то не понял?

Comment: == это не присваивание - это проверка на равенство с присвоением результата `ViewBag.M`

Comment: да просмотрел. а что Вы хотите сделать таким образом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство `ViewData.ModelMetadata` используется для хранения метаданных модели. Метаданные помещает туда поставщик метаданных модели. Можно написать свой поставщик метаданных, но в Asp MVC уже есть реализованный поставщик, который включен по умолчанию - [DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider(v=vs.118).aspx). Из его названия ясно откуда он берет метаданные - он получает их из атрибутов моделей. Например вы можете указать `DisplayName` для свойства вашей модели вот так:

```
public class AnyModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Поставищик метаданных прочитает атрибут свойства `Name`, поймет, что в качестве названия поля `Name` надо использовать слово `Имя`, сохранит эту информацию в `ViewData.ModelMetadata`, откуда она будет прочитана в момент рендерига представления.

Исходя из написанного ответы на ваши вопросы следующие:

**Почему в методе действия Index `ViewData.ModelMetadata == null`?**

Чтобы прочитать метаданные модели, надо знать, что будет использоваться в качестве модели. Но это будет известно только после выхода из метода контроллера. Поэтому поставщик метаданных выполняет свою работу на более поздней стадии обработки запроса. Сначала должен выполниться метод контроллера и только потом, можно будет считать метаданные модели и поместить их в `ViewData.ModelMetadata`

**Почему в представлении `ViewData.ModelMetadata` уже не равняется null, хотя никакой модели не передается?**

Если вы решите реализовать свой поставщик метаданных модели, вам придется создать класс, унаследованный от [ModelMetadataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataprovider(v=vs.118).aspx). Основной метод, который вам придется переопределить имеет следуюущую сигнатуру:

```
public abstract ModelMetadata GetMetadataForType(
    Func<Object> modelAccessor,
    Type modelType)
```

То есть вы должны будете вычислить метаданные модели опираясь на *тип* модели. Хотя вы и не указываете тип модели у слаботипизированного представления, нельзя сказать, что этого типа у представления нет. Слаботипизированное представление рассчитано на работу с моделями типа `System.Object`, и вот [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460372(v=vs.100).aspx) вы можете увидеть, что у него есть свойство `Model` типа `Object`.

То есть, когда вы возвращаете из метода контроллера слаботипизированное представление, на одном из последуюущих этапов обработки запроса будет вызван метод `GetMetadataForType` текущего провайдера метаданных, и в этот метод в качестве параметра `modelType` будет передан тип `Object` и метод должен будет вернуть осмысленный ответ. [DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelmetadataprovider(v=vs.118).aspx) возвращает ответ отличный от null, и если вы посмотрите в дебаггере на то, что в итоге записывается в `ViewData.ModelMetadata`вы увидете, что для некоторых свойств выставлены дефолтные значения, которые очевидно имеют какой-то смысл даже в контексте "отсутсвующей" модели:

[image: Deafult ModelMetadata]